# Scala: Map part of Json to Object with playframework

Tags: json, scala, playframework, mapping

I'm relatively new to Scala. I would like to map part of my Json to my Object. Code looks like this:

```
    def seasons = (json \\ "season")
```

case class:

```
  case class Season(startDate: LocalDate, endDate: LocalDate)
```

json-structure:

```
[
      {
        "id": "",
        "name": "",
        "season": {
          "start": "0",
          "end": "0"
        }
      }
]
```

I would somehow like to end up with a List[Season], so I can loop through it.

### Question #2

```
json-structure:

[
      {
        "id": "",
        "name": "",
        "season": {
          "start": "0",
          "end": "0"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "",
        "name": "",
        "season": {
          "start": "0",
          "end": "0"
        }
      }...
]
```

Json (which is a JsValue btw) brings multiple regions as can be seen above. Case classed are provided (Region holds a Season), naming is the same as in json.
Formats look like this:

```
implicit val seasonFormat: Format[Season] = Json.format[Season]
implicit val regionFormat: Format[Region] = Json.format[Region]
```

So what would I need to call in order to get a List[Region]? I thought of something like `regionsJson.as[List[Region]]` as I defined the Format, which provides me the Read/Write possibilities. But unfortunately, it's not working.

What is the best way doing this? I've tried it with an JsArray, but I have difficulties with mapping it...

Any input would be much appreciated!

Comment: Solution for question2: regionsJSON.validate[List[Region]].map(_.toList)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some changes to your original `case class` and renamed its fields to match json fields.

The following code does parsing of the json into `Seq[Session]`

```scala
import java.time.LocalDate
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Season(start: LocalDate, end: LocalDate)
implicit val sessionFormat: Format[Season] = Json.format[Season]

val json =
  """
    |[
    |      {
    |        "id": "",
    |        "name": "",
    |        "season": {
    |          "start": "2020-10-20",
    |          "end": "2020-10-22"
    |        }
    |      }
    |]
    |""".stripMargin

val seasonsJson: collection.Seq[JsValue] = Json.parse(json) \\ "season"
val seasons: collection.Seq[Season] = seasonsJson.map(_.as[Season])
seasons.foreach(println)
```

Please note that I changed the data of your json and instead of `0`, which is not a valid date, I provided dates in iso format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

The above code works with play-json version 2.9.0.

---UPDATE---

Following up comment by @cchantep.

Method `as` will produce an exception if json cannot be mapped in case class, a non-exception option is to use `asOpt` that does not throw an exception but returns a `None` if mapping is not possible.

Comment: `.as` is unsafe/not recommended

Comment: Ok - so I need a format as an implicit in order to get the mapping.
What if I would like to map the full JSON to a List of Objects? The JSON is a JsValue. Am I defining a format for as well?

Comment: @Remo. These objects should be of a concrete type. These types must each have an implicit format provided. The implicit format is only needed for generic type `T` used in methods `as[T]` or `asOpt[T]`. Thus, it's not needed for JsValue

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc As far as I understood your comment, this is what I've done. Unfortunately, it's still not working as I get a JSValidationError(error.expected.jsobject). Updated the question for more insights. Could you help me out with this as well?

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc got it :) regionsJSON.validate[List[Region]].map(_.toList). As simple as that.